# Using self compiled GWT SDK Version with gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: gwt, maven, maven-plugin

I have a problem declaring dependencies on a new gwt version that I compiled myself and deployed in my own repository. I followed the instructions written here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html but gwt-maven-plugin seems to be looking for the dependencies only in the central repository. I couldn't find a way to make it search in my rep. 
Can you tell me how to do that or where I can find a solution?

My configuration looks like this:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies> 
                ...

   </plugin>
```

And I get the error message:

> Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.my.groupId:requestfactory-server:jar:2.4.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Regards, 
Arne

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to me not with gwt, but with `requestfactory-server`.  Is it your custom component?

Try to run maven in offline mode to see if that artifact is copied into your local repository.

```
mvn --offline
```

or

```
mvn -o
```

Comment: Hmm this is strange. When I run it in offline mode it does say that it is not available in my local repository. The jar is in the .m2 folder though and is added to my project dependencies. Only the plugin can't find it.

Comment: @Ame.  Are you running on Windows XP? If so, then you will have to move your repository to `C:\m2-repo` or some path that does not have spaces in it ( by default it's in `C:\Documents and Settings\username` ) and adjust your `settings.xml` accordingly.  `gwt-maven-plugin` is one of those that cannot cope with spaces in local m2 repository path.  There are bugs about this problem in their JIRA.

Comment: No I am using win7. Maybe there is a problem because I changed where windows stores most of my user data. what i think is strange, that everything works fine in my project. when I add a dependency the jar is shown as a maven-dependency in eclipse and it compiles like it should. only the plugin is complaining.

Comment: @Ame. Can you verify that path to your `.m2` directory does not contain spaces?  That's definitely a problem with gwt-maven-plugin.

Comment: ah sry, I thought that was a windows xp related issue. That's why I didn't answer that. But no. There are no spaces. (E:\Windows\.m2) Maybe it is this not standard path thats making problems.

Comment: @Arne. No, only spaces matter, your setup should be fine for that plugin to work.  Can you verify that you do see a `requestfactory-server` in your local repository?

Comment: yes it is there: E:\Windows\.m2\repository\com\my\groupId\requestfactory-server\

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting requestfactory-server in the plugin's dependencies?

AFAIK it won't make use of it. You'll have to override the gwt-servlet version, that gwt-maven-plugin has a dependency on, with your own `${gwt.version}` though (even if I actually don't understand why it has a dependency on it at all)

Comment: I had all the gwt-libraries as dependencies, maybe it was a bad example to put the requestfactory-server one in here. but good to know i don't need it. I figured the problem out. I used my own group-id for the my self-comiled gwt.jars so it wouldn't be confused with published versions later. (Made sense to me when I did it) This way the gwt-version the plugin uses wasn't overriden. So if I don't put any dependencies the problem I had at the beginning is gone. What I still have is that I can't put my own versions of gwt as dependencies of the plugin. Not sure if this is necessary though. thanks

Comment: You should use the GWT's groupId and artifactId, but a SNAPSHOT version, e.g.: com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.4-SNAPSHOT.